# Servlets - Can we change character encoding after the default is set

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, filter

I have a filter where I'm first fetching the request param and then setting the Character Encoding

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    final String name = request.getParameter("name");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

This is not working. 
As explained in [request.getCharacterEncoding() returns NULL... why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358101/request-getcharacterencoding-returns-null-why) that if we dont set the encoding the default is set.

Can we change the encoding once the default is set ? If not what is the exact reason

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
final String name = request.getParameter("name");
```

> Can we change the encoding once the default is set ? If not what is
>   the exact reason

Yes we can. But you have to be sure setting encoding is executed **BEFORE** reading parameters

Comment: Thanks @Aramks, the above snippet would work, my question is why the reverse is not possible. i.e getting the  param and then setting the encoding